# Image doesn't show on cardview

Tags: java, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use     `firebase` storage and   `firebase` `DataBase` to upload and retrieve the files and strings from the database and storage.

When I upload a picture from my smartphone and add a text. The picture gets added to firebase storage, and the text and picture `url` gets added in the database.

Then when I want to receive those from database, I do so and follow they guidelines.

I have a `cardview` and the picture gets added on the `cardview` and the text as well. But the picture only gets added to the `cardview` if the image is a downloaded image, meaning not from my camera. The photos that I have taken with my camera don't show up how long I wait. It's only about 2mb data anyways. The downloaded pictures are like 500kb, they do show up on `cardview`. But not pictures taken from my smartphone. Why is that.

Comment: Please add the code you have written so far.

Comment: I can't because it alot of code, I tried copy and paste but stackoverflow has some bug where it will say "there is code which isn't formatted correctly" even though it's. All of my code was inside code bracelets.

Comment: Do you think you know the issue here?

Comment: Without the code I cannot do much.

Comment: i have added the code in the answer field. Because i couldn't edit my question and add code there unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I manages to solve my issue:

this is how!

I used Picasso library, and my code was like this:

```
Picasso.with(mCtx)
            .load(uploadImage.getImageUrl())
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);
```

i changed it to:

```
Picasso.with(mCtx)
            .load(uploadImage.getImageUrl())
            //.fit()
            //.centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);
```

I still don't understand though. Why can't I use `fit()` and `centerCrop()` to retrieve my images from the database that was images taken with my camera app. But it works if I have downloaded images from internet.